# Bundler::LockfileError falsely reported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler, rbenv

I recently began using `rbenv` to manage my projects, switching from `rvm`. It has been a very painful experience, but seems to be improving. I am not using the gemset plugin, as I'm relying on Bundler to manage gems for my projects. I'm using the following command:

```
bundle install --path .gems
```

to install my gems in each project's app root.

Suddenly, my most important project is reporting this error:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:33:in `initialize': Your Gemfile.lock contains merge conflicts. (Bundler::LockfileError)
Run `git checkout HEAD -- Gemfile.lock` first to get a clean lock
```

But there are no merge conflicts at all in my `Gemfile.lock`. I refuse to delete it and go through updating all of these gems again. How can I get Bundler to stop falsely reporting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code from Bundler that implements that check:

```
  if lockfile.match(/<<<<<<<|=======|>>>>>>>|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|/)
    raise LockfileError, "Your Gemfile.lock contains merge conflicts.\n" \
      "Run `git checkout HEAD -- Gemfile.lock` first to get a clean lock."
  end
```

Check that your `Gemfile.lock` doesn't contain those stray conflict markers.